# CUDA 11 runs out of memory when running mae_vit_* models but CUDA 10 works

Tags: python, pytorch, cuda, gpu

I'm encountering a memory issue while trying to run the `mae_vit_large_patch16_dec512d8` and `mae_vit_huge_patch16_dec512d8` models from the [Mae repository on GitHub](https://github.com/facebookresearch/mae). I am training on a single 112x112 image; this is my "dataset". I can successfully run the `mae_vit_base_patch16_dec512d8` model, but when I attempt to run the larger models, I encounter the following error:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory
```

Some of the testing I want to do requires I test the larger models as well.

Here are some details about my setup:

- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 with 8GB GDDR6 memory
- RAM: 32 GB
- Batch size: 1

Input image size: 112x112 pixels

I'm using a relatively small input size and a batch size of 1. Since I'm training on a single small PNG image for multiple iterations, I assumed that my hardware should have ample memory to accommodate these models. However, this error persists.

Does anyone have insights into what might be causing this "out of memory" error when running these larger models? Some of the testing I want to do requires I test the larger models. Is there a potential workaround or configuration adjustment that could help resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi dimes, could you add some details about how you are running these tests, what worked and what didn't work? That way, there's more handholds and footholds for folks to see what the problem might be. Right now, you're presenting basically a smooth wall to climb.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by downgrading my CUDA version to 10.2 (from 11.8) and installing pytorch CUDA 11.2 with python 3.6. I am now able to run all models.

While this solves the immediate problem, it doesn't explain it.
If anyone can explain why this "fixed" my memory issue, I would be very grateful.